# Ag grid Quick filter error cell rows are not filtering

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I'm trying to filter only error cell rows using `'setQuickFilter()'`.

I have tried the below with sample error cells `[ 'N/A', 'E45' ]` but no luck. Any expert solutions.

**HTML**

```
   <a (click)="onQuickFilterChanged()">
                    <span class="error"></span>
                    <span>Error</span>
                  </a>

<ag-grid-angular *ngIf="!cLoader" #agGrid id="cisGrid" class="ag-theme-balham cis-grid excelsheet"
            [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef" [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents" [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
            [columnTypes]="columnTypes" [rowData]="rowData" [gridOptions]="gridOptions" [context]="context"
            [stopEditingWhenGridLosesFocus]="false" (cellValueChanged)="onCellValueChanged($event)"
            suppressHorizontalScroll="false" (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)">
          </ag-grid-angular>
```

**TS**

```
 onQuickFilterChanged() { 
        this.gridOptions.api.setQuickFilter(this.fil());
        this.gridOptions.api.onFilterChanged();
      }

      fil() {
        return [
          'N/A', 'E45'
        ];
      }
```

**Before Filter results**

[image]

**Expected filter results after clicking the error text link.**

[image]

Comment: You can use space separated string for multiple values. But values are connected with and clause. If you want different conditions you should create custom filter.

Comment: I have tried with space also like return ['N/A E45' ]. Still it is not working.

Comment: not array just string.